# How to find length of list of pair

Tags: coq

I have calculated the length of list by function (`length`).Now I want to find the length of a list of pairs (`natprod`) and make a list from the  first element of each pair in the list. I have a problem in calculating the length of a list of pair, because there is no `nil`/`[]`  at the end of lists which may be used for termination of loop. 
An example to clear my point would be `[(2,5)(1,5)(3,7)]->[2,1,3]`. 
Please guide me.

```
Fixpoint length (l: natlist) : nat :=
  match l with
  | [] => O
  | _ :: l' => S (length l')
  end.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `[]` is every list, including lists of pairs.
You don't need to compute the length of the list however...

What you're looking for is the `map` function.
Basically `map f [x1 ; ... ; xn]` is `[f x1 ; ... ; f xn]`.
Its type would be `map : forall {A B : Type} (f : A -> B) (l : list A), list B`.
Or if you really want to stick to your `natprod`, `natlist` and so on:
`map : (natprod -> nat) -> list natprod -> natlist`...

```
Fixpoint map {A B : Type} (f : A -> B) (l : list A) : list B :=
  match l with
  | [] => []
  | x :: l => f x :: map f l
  end.
```

In your case you want to `map` the `snd` function which returns the second element of a pair: `map snd l`.

Comment: I want to make list of keys in this way,but there is error messageDefinition mymap := list (nat*V).
  Definition empty1 : mymap := nil.
  Fixpoint lookup1 (x: key) (m: mymap) : list nat :=
    match m with
    | (a,v)::al => if x =? a then (cons a nil) else (lookup x m)
    | nil => nil
    end.

Comment: I have list of pairs in map,want to get natlist with first element of each pair.

Comment: I have few line code ,I do't know whats the problem with this. Plz guide me Definition t:=N.
  Definition A:=Type.
  Definition ad:=Type.
  Definition key := N.
  Inductive Map :=
    | M0 : Map
    | M1 : ad -> A -> Map
    | M2 : Map -> Map -> Map.
  Definition empty : t A := M0 A. @Winterhalter

Comment: I added the map function. If you want to add more examples of what you wrote, please do it by editing your original post.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion,but I want to solve the error in above map function so that i can execute it (Line Definition empty :t A:=M0 A.)gives error.

Comment: Can you add it to your post then? With all the definitions.